# What does this command do?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, command-line

```
cat telephone.txt | cat | cat | sed -e "s/t/T/" | tee cible | wc -l
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a command like that, try each piece to see what it does.

For example, run each of these to see what they do:

```
cat telephone.txt
cat telephone.txt | cat
cat telephone.txt | cat | cat
cat telephone.txt | cat | cat | sed -e "s/t/T/"
cat telephone.txt | cat | cat | sed -e "s/t/T/" | tee cible
cat telephone.txt | cat | cat | sed -e "s/t/T/" | tee cible | wc -l
```

Once you do that, you'll see that:

```
cat telephone.txt <-- reads file
cat <-- reads stdin and prints to stdout (from comments)
cat <-- reads stdin and prints to stdout (from comments)
sed -e "s/t/T/" <-- replaces the first lower case t on each line with an upper case T
tee cible <-- reads stdin and prints to stdout and also writes it to a file called "cible"
wc -l <-- counts the lines of stdout from above
```

Comment: I would debate on second and third `cat` do nothing. It still reads stdin and outputs everything to stdout. Yes, it doesn't change the stream, but still it does some work, which on huge files will eat quite a time.

Comment: ("Useless Use of cat") * 3   :-)

Comment: In my bash shell above `tee cible ` syntax will store to file cible only the last line of `cat telephone.txt` . If this works for you it might be a different tee version, but in my case to print in screen , sed and then store all lines of telephone.txt to file cible i have to use `tee -a cible`  (append)

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou: Then there's something wrong with your system.

Comment: @Scott According to the manual -a is required for append. Iam not the only one that i have to use `tee -a` : http://askubuntu.com/questions/808539/how-to-append-tee-to-a-file-in-bash

Comment: OK, if there was a loop, invoking `tee` for each line separately, your comments would make some sense. Note that the question you linked to refers to explicitly invoking `tee` twice. But, in this compound command, `tee` is invoked only once, so `cible` should end up with every line of `telephone.txt` (as modified `t` → `T` by `sed`). I stand by my statement.

Comment: $ cat test.txt | sed -e 's/e/E/' | tee testOut.txt | cat
`OnE
Two
ThrEe
Four
FivE`
$ cat testOut.txt 
`OnE
Two
ThrEe
Four
FivE` Each number is on a seperate line. Tested in GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)